# how to limit the amount of data being sent by the client through websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, limit

I am using the `ws` module and I'd like to limit the amount of data being sent by the client over websocket to 1Mb.  This will prevent a malicious user from sending huge amounts of data (in terms of GB) causing the server to run out of memory, which would cause denial of service errors for every normal user. 
For example, example Express allows to specify the max size of a post request body like so:

```
bodyParser.json({limit:'1Mb'})
```

How I do something similar with the `ws` module?
I tried

```
var ws = require('ws').Server
var wsserver = new ws({port:8080, limit:'1Mb'})
```

But this of course doesn't work.
 I want the transmission of data to be interrupted (after 1Mb is exceeded) and the websocket connection to be closed. How can I do that?

There must be a way to limit the frames of data coming from the client...

Comment: guess no one knows yet ... https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/513 ... https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=limit

Comment: Which `ws` library are you using?  If there isn't an answer in the documentation for the webSocket library you are using, then an answer can only be determined by studying the code for the library to see if it has any sort of limit capability or understanding where the code could be changed to add such a limit.  It does sound like a reasonable thing to want.

Comment: @jfriend00 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws here it is. Apparently in the documentation there is no property of the option argument which would do so. Maybe there is a method of the wsServer instance which can set the limit. I will check it out.

Comment: yay: https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-node#initialization-options has `maxLength`

Answer (score 12):

That ability does not (currently) exist in that library.

Poking around their source code, it appears that the place to start would be `processPacket()` method in https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/Receiver.js .

Once you have the packet header available, you can see the size of the message being sent.  If it's above a certain threshold, there should be a way to close the connection before all of the bytes are even hitting your network.

Of course, the nice thing to do would be to fork their repository, issue a feature request, add in a configuration option that defaults to not taking any action if it's not set (don't break backwards compatibility), and submit a pull request.

If they like it, they'll merge.  If not, you'll still be able to merge their future versions into your own repo and stay up to date without having to re-do your work each time they submit a new release.

Comment: There are a couple of instances of `packets with length spanning more than 32 bit is currently not supported`.  Changing the max length condition that leads to that error could be an easy way to do this, although I'm not sure what happens to frames that claim a certain length but actually go on for much longer.

Comment: The case of packet lengths spanning more than 32 bits is specified in the WebSockets RFC as a valid message length that takes special handling due to it changing the size of the frame header. A message that size would be over 4GB.

Comment: There is also a valid case for messages where there is more data in the TCP frame after the total length of the WebSockets frame has been reached, due to a way that TCP handles very small messages over high latency connections.  Nagle's Algorithm will merge multiple messages together at the TCP layer, causing multiple WebSockets frames to come in the same network read, potentially carrying missed messages if the server doesn't check for them... Though this only legitimately happens on a series of very short messages... It would never legitimately occur on a message nearly 4GB in size..

Comment: The error message I copied is misleading.  It is talking about frames with a payload length that spans more than 32 bits.  Its actually nothing to do with packets.

Comment: Also, the length taking more than 32 bits is not a special case; the special cases are at over 8 bits and over 16 bits.  This is an issue with JavaScript not having a good way to represent 64 bit integers, so the maintainer opted to arbitrarily limit payload lengths to 32 bits.

Comment: Yes, IP packets typically get fragmented, and TCP is quite good at handling that and generally sets the TCP frame size to comfortably fit within the end-to-end minimum (sane) MTU for the various physical and data link layers that the message will go through. The RFC does go into detail to make sure anyone implementing a client or server takes care to handle fragmented messages. I should have double checked to see what the special case boundaries were; I was running off of remembering from years ago when I last looked at that detail.